# is there a way to send data from diffrent forms at the same time with only 1 submit button?

Tags: php, html, forms, submit

This is my body i want to submit more than 1 data from diffrent forms at the same time with the same button is it possible in php? i want first form send the selected one second form send the text value...

```
<body>      
<div id="kategoriler">
<h4>Kategoriler</h4>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<select name="mydropdown">
<option value="Oteller">Oteller</option>
<option value="Restaurant">Restaurant</option>
<option value="Cafe">Cafe</option>
<option value="Bar">Bar</option>
<option value="Köy">Köy</option>
</select>
</form>
</div>
<div id ="text">
<h4>Başlik</h4>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<input type="text" name="baslik" value="" maxlength="100" />
<h4>Açıklama</h4>
<textarea rows="30" cols="70">
 Buraya yazın...
</textarea>
</form>
</div>
<div id="bresim">
<h4>Başlik Resmi</h4>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Resmi Seçin:</label>
<input name="uploaded" type="file" />
</form>
</div>
<div id="ekle">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Eklemek için tıklayın!" />
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: my answer doesn't work!, the only way is via AJAX, please check @Phil's answer. Sorry.

Comment: maybe this code is just an example, but, why are you creating 3 forms for this????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using jQuery...

First, give your forms and submit button some IDs (I used #form1, #form2, and #submit). Then...

**Edit:** Here's a non-AJAX solution that takes advantage of the fact that the forms post to the same URL.

When the submit button is clicked, move/append the text input `$(input[name=baslik])` to the second form and then submit it. This solution doesn't need the jQuery Form plugin and doesn't use AJAX:

```
$("#form2").submit(function() {
    $(input[name=baslik]).appendTo($(this));
});
```

**Original, AJAX solution:**

If you want AJAX, you can use the [jQuery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/).

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#form1, #form2').ajaxForm(function() { 
        // optionally do stuff here after forms submitted
    });

    $('#submit').click(function() {
        $('#form1, #form2').ajaxSubmit();
        return false; 
    });
});
```

You can't use jQuery's `$(form).serialize()` because it does not work on file fields. This solution also assumes you want to use AJAX.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

remove the input that submits, and add a link outside every form with the javascript that submits all:
(also add an ID to everyform, so you can call them via this javascript)

```
function submitAll(){
   document.forms["IDform1"].submit();
   document.forms["IDform2"].submit();
}
```

EDIT: this doesn't work, the only way is via AJAX, please check @Phil's answer!

Comment: thanks alot mate so i need to look into javascript at first thanks mate have a nice day.

Comment: Are both submits handled in the same request to the server?

Comment: @jackJoe Does it really work? What is the URL in the browser after submition of those forms? The URL of the second form?

Comment: This method doesn't work because only the first form will be submitted (since they're both POSTing to the same URL). If they posted to different URLs, only the second one would be submitted.

Comment: @Karolis you're right, I forgot about that "tiny" detail, I focused on the how, shame on me!  I suppose the only way will be via an AJAX solution.

Comment: @jackjoe I believe it can be done with non-AJAX solution too ;)

Comment: @Phil the simplest way would be to merge the forms into a single one at the html, but as an exercise this is a nice question.

Comment: @jackjoe yeah that's what I would have done heh. Simpler, cleaner, and no need to think!

Answer (score 2):

One option would be forcing javascript being used: launch a javascript handler that collects the values, submits a ajax request, or even writes a form and submits it.

[Jquery](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) can easily be used to to loop through all form values.

So something like:

```
$("#first_form").submit(function() {
    //collect all values here
    first_form_data = $("#first_form").serialize();
    second_form_data = $("#second_form").serialize();

    $.ajax({
         url: ..,
         data: first_form_data + "&" + second_form_data,
         success: function(data) {

         }
    }

    //let’s not submit the form
    return false;
}
```