# send data from two forms with one button to one php receiver with ajaxSubmit() function

Tags: php, jquery, forms, submit

I have two forms in html:

```
<form id="form1" action="update.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username1">
</form>

<form id="form2" action="update.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username2">
</form>

<button type="button" onclick="submitTwoForms();">Send</button>
```

Now I send these two forms to one php page named "update.php" by using jQuery Form Plugin.
Javascript like this:

```
function submitTwoForms() {
         $('#form1, #form2').ajaxSubmit();
}
```

The Problem is, update.php can only get the data from the form1, namely the username1.
How can update.php get the data from form1 AND form2 at the same time?

My update.php like this:

```
<?php
$user1 = $_POST['username1'];
$user2 = $_POST['username2'];
?>
```

And I want to keep these:

1. I want use ajaxSubmit() function because it can handle file uploading.
2. I want to keep two forms in html, not one.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery Form Plugin and go like this
**Method1**

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#form1, #form2').ajaxForm(function() { 
            // optionally do stuff here after forms submitted
        });

        $('#submit').click(function() {
            $('#form1, #form2').ajaxSubmit();
            return false; 
        });
    });
```

**Method2:**
try this [Demo Here](http://plungjan.name/test/duosubmit.html):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        $.post($("#form1").attr("action"), $("#form1").serialize(),
          function() {
            $.post($("#form2").attr("action"), $("#form2").serialize(),
              function() {
                alert('Both forms submitted');
              });
          });
      });
  });
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.
but I don't really unterstand.
could you please explain more?
i try to do something like
    
function submitTwoForms() {
         $('#form1, #form2').ajaxForm();
         $('#form1, #form2').ajaxSubmit();
}

Comment: Here is a similar thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857038/is-there-a-way-to-send-data-from-diffrent-forms-at-the-same-time-with-only-1-sub?rq=1
Please let me know, if this helps

Comment: hi, I have followed and tried the ajax solution in your link, but still only the data from first form can be passed to php receiver.

Comment: hi, I think ajax seriallize can not handle file uploading.
And I added the code of my php and changed the javascript code. maybe it would be more clear about my problem.

Comment: sry, your first method is what I want to find it out, but still does not work for me. I will try exactly step by step the link that you gived to me and then send you some feedbacks. thx a lot!

Comment: hi, here is me again. your third method doesn't work, because the php can only get the value from $("#frm1").submit(). So is your another both methods, or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: where is your value? Assuming this is test code you stated as example, still, are you missing that? 
<input type="text" name="username2" value="1">

Comment: Tried this one myself and working like breeze. Let me know... Cheers :)

Comment: hi, I think there is a missunderstanding. you pass the two forms to php file not at the same time , but one by one. It means, the php file get at first form1 and then do something. After that php file get form2 and do something. what I need is the php file get form1 and form2 at the same time, and write all data from form1 and form 2 once into SQL. Or it is just impossible?

Comment: Can't say impossible, but what do you mean, when you say 'at the same time'? Describe, why you can not Create "SQL" after both the forms get posted?

Comment: in the php file, if I use the command likes 
<$query = "insert into testTable values ('$username1', '$username2')";>, 
it will create two items in SQL with your post method. 
my idea was that the php file gets username1 and username2 once together, and executes the sql command once, and creates one item in database.

Comment: your post method send the two forms separately, and invoke php file twice. that is, first time, php get only username1 and create a item only with username1 in database. second time php get only username2 and create a item only with username2.

Comment: can be solved by Global variable, SESSION. Nothing unsolvable here..give a shot, you will make it :)

Comment: Sol2: Create record with a username1, get the ID of the last inserted element(mysql_insert_id), then update username2. Makes sense? anyway, you can mark this an answer, and start a new thread, if you wish.

Comment: ok, thx! your suggestion about using Global variable SESSION is a good direction that I will do some homework. And I had also your Sol2 in my head, but what I cannot solve is how can I save mysql_insert_id from the first php invoking and use it later for second php invoking.